# Why does 172.16.0.0/12 equal to range 172.16.0.0 -- 172.31.255.255?

Tags: networking, subnet

So we have a private network:

`172.16.0.0/12`

that means:

```
10101100.00010000.00000000.00000000 (value: 172.16.0.0)
11111111.11110000.00000000.00000000 (subnet mask of /12)
```

How does that translate to the: `172.16.0.0 -- 172.31.255.255` range? Based on the subnet mask, if I understand it correctly, it should be `172.0.255.255 -- 172.15.255.255`. Where does `31` come from?

Comment: @Colt it's related, though not a duplicate. That's similar to saying that question "why doesn't this Java algorithm work" is a duplicate to Oracle javadoc. Just for future reference.

Comment: Your question, which is off-topic for other reasons too (such as, for example, seeking learning material), is completely answered in the _Canonical Question_ linked, which [is there in part to _prevent_ these off-topic questions](https://serverfault.com/help/duplicates).

Comment: This is not just related, it is exactly the sort of question the duplicate was intended to prevent. The community has long ago decided that we do not want yet more beginner questions about subnetting, and prepared the linked Q&A specifically for you and others who are trying to learn this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the netmask denotes the network part, you must invert it to get the host part.

So the host part of a `/12` network is `000FFFFF` or `00000000`-`000FFFFF`. If you have a network 172.16.0.0 or `AC100000`, the low address is `AC100000 | 00000000` and the high address is `AC100000 | 000FFFFF`

```
10101100.00010000.00000000.00000000 (low address, 172.16.0.0)
00000000.00001111.11111111.11111111 (host mask)
10101100.00011111.11111111.11111111 (high address, 172.31.255.255)
```

Comment: Thanks, I see my error... I had the mask inverted, and as such, it didn't make sense to me.